# Having trouble understanding this nested loop

Tags: java

I haven't done any coding in awhile, so I'm refreshing my knowledge. I'm looking through my old midterms and I'm having trouble understanding this particular code of a nested loop and why it prints out the output that it does.

```
public class Loops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        while (i < 4){
         System.out.println ('*');
         for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
         System.out.print('*');
         }
         i += 1;
        }
        System.out.println ("\nWow");
        while (i > 0){
         System.out.print('*');
         i -= 1;
        }
        
}
}
```

I ran the code and it gave this output and I'm trying to understand why:

```
*
*
**
***
***
Wow
****
```

When I try to figure it out I end up with

```
*
**
***
****
Wow
****
```

**My thought process**: i is 0,
i is less than 4 so
**print a star**
j = i, i is 0, 0 is not greater than 0. so exit and add 1 to i.
i is 1,
i is less than 4 so
**print a star**
j = 1, i is 1, 1 is greater than 0, so **print a star**.
decrement j, so j is now 0, 0 is not greater than 0 so exit and add 1 to i.
i is 2,
i is less than 4 so
**print a star**
j = 2, 2 is greater than 0, so ** print a star**, decrement by 1, j is now 1. 1 is greater than 0 so **print a star** decrement by 1, j is now 0, 0 is not greater than 0, so exit and add 1 to i.
i is now 3.
3 is less than 4.
so **print a star**
j = 3. 3 is greater than 0 so **print a star**. decrement by 1, j is now 2, 2 is greater than 0 so
**print a star**. decrement by 1, j is now 1. 1 is greater than 0 so **print a star**. Now we decrement j, j is  now 0 so we exit and add 1 to i. i is now 4, so we go to the next bit of code and **print "Wow"**. since i is 4 the while loop will **print 4 stars**

Am I understanding while loops wrong?

Comment: As far as I can see you understand the logic correctly. You just need to pay attention to `println` and `print`. Some stars are printed with and some without moving to next line.

Comment: I feel dumb now. I'm so used to always using println that I forgot print existed.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand nested loops if the indentation is all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

Let's just look at this bit, since there seems to be no confusion about the final part:

```
while (i < 4){
    System.out.println ('*');
    for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    i += 1;
}
```

This is what's printed for every value of `i`:

| `i` | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | `*\n` |
| 1 | `*\n*` |
| 2 | `*\n**` |
| 3 | `*\n***` |

Concatenate all that, and you get `*\n*\n**\n***\n***`, or:

```
*
*
**
***
***
```

Note that `println()` adds a newline to the output, while `print()` does not.

Comment: Thank you, this made it easy to understand. I forgot that print existed and just assumed it was all println. Should've looked more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

So for this you just need to understand how println() method works.

The println() method is similar to print() method except that it moves the cursor to the next line **after printing the result**.

Hope this solves your doubt !!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
        while (i < 4){ //the last iteration is i=3 (3<4=true, in loop); but 
                       //the end is i += 1 (is 4) 
         System.out.println ('*');
         for(int j=i; j>0; j--){ //first 0 is not 0>0(false), zero is skip
         System.out.print('*');
         }
         i += 1;
        }

      //and after upper loop i =4

        System.out.println ("\nWow");
        while (i > 0){ 
         System.out.print('*');  //four *, 4,3,2,1
         i -= 1;
        }
```